# nuget update script for all projects in the solution

Tags: nuget

I need to upgrade several projects in VS2013 solution. There are lot of libraries, that depend on each other and a lot of projects in the solution. I don't want to upgrade it all manually. And I don't want to upgrade all so I cant use update all button in "manage nuget packages". What are my options? Ideally I would like to be able to set a list of libraries I want to update. And run a script that would check every project against this list and make updates. Is there a nuget api for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write a PowerShell script and then run it from the Package Manager Console. You can update all packages in a specific project by using the [Update-Package command](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference):

```
Update-Package -Project MyProject
```

You can also just update specific packages in a project:

```
Update-Package MyPackage -Project MyProject
```

Or you can update specific packages for the entire solution:

```
Update-Package MyPackage
```

I would also have everything under source control so you can rollback if the script updated the wrong thing.

Comment: How do I update the package for the whole solution, except for, say 2 projects? Any api or script command to get all projects, except for the ones with Test prefix and update package for them?

Comment: NuGet has a `Get-Project -All` command which will give you all the projects in the solution. You can then filter them out based on the name. So something like the following would filter them based on the name `get-project -all | where { $_.Name.StartsWith("Test") -eq $false }`

Comment: Is there a way to perform package install in case previous version of the package was installed? I mean I had package abc.v1 . Now I want to install abc.v2 . And I need to uninstall abc.v1 first as it doesnt support upgrade to v2. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sure. For this you could use the `Uninstall-Package` and `Install-Package` commands.

Comment: How can I only install some packages in condition of other package presence/absence? I mean I may want to install package aaa only if there are bbb and ccc and if there is ddd I want to upgrade aaa to aaa.v42

Comment: You can get the packages used by a project using `Get-Package -ProjectName MyProject`.

Comment: Yes, I can, but how to conditionally apply install/uninstall, based on what packages I get?

Comment: You can do this with PowerShell. One way would be to use the where clause. `$packages = get-package -projectname MyProject | where { $_.Id -eq 'jquery' }` Then count the number of items returned `if ($packages.count -gt 0) { 'Do something' }`